# Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ClassCastException: Play 2.5.4 - Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, code-injection

I'm trying to create a log filter, base on [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.4/ScalaHttpFilters) but i can't figure out what is going on.

I got thios error message :

> Unexpected exception ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the
>   following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lplay.mvc.EssentialFilter;   at
>   Filters.(Filters.scala:11)   while locating Filters   while
>   locating play.http.HttpFilters
>       for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaHttpFiltersAdapter.(HttpFilters.scala:63)
>   while locating play.api.http.JavaHttpFiltersAdapter   while locating
>   play.api.http.HttpFilters
>       for parameter 3 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
>   while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler   while
>   locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
>       for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.(Application.scala:221)   at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)   while
>   locating play.api.DefaultApplication   while locating
>   play.api.Application
>
> 1 error

But my LoggingFilter extends EssentialFilter (I copied the documentation code).
Do I need to bind something for Guice ?

Here my built.sbt:

```
    name := """abc"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  filters,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0",
  "org.webjars" % "react" % "0.13.1"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Here my plugins.sbt :

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Eclpise Plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")

// transform JSX assets to js
addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.5.0")
```

Comment: Did you put your class in the root package? If not, you should add this in your conf: `play.http.filters=com.example.MyFilters`. Also, check if your imports are correct..

Comment: Yes, insan-e, I did the same that explained in doc : 
"play.http.filters = Filters" in application.conf & "Filters" class in app/ folder.

Comment: I also have this problem. I'm using java and I have exactly followed the documentation

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this problem.  I have the exact same issue.  Followed documentation to add a CORSFilter.  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in the DefaultHttpFilters class's constructor.  The error is present in 2.5.4 and will be fixed in the 2.5.5 milestone which is not yet available and does not have a due date.  I would like a workaround for this as well.

Url to the issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/6238

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will help any of you with this problem.  But I did get my CORSFilter to work.  (Play 2.5.4)

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.mvc.EssentialAction;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;

public class MyFilters extends EssentialFilter implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    private CORSFilter corsFilter;


    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return corsFilter.asJava().apply(next);
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        EssentialFilter[] result = new EssentialFilter[1];
        result[0] = this;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Also added this into the application.conf

```
play.filters.cors{
# allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Singleton
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    private final Environment env;
    private final CORSFilter corsFilter;

    @Inject
    public Filters(Environment env, CORSFilter corsFilter) {
        this.env = env;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] { corsFilter.asJava() };
    }

}
```

the point is: corsFilter.asJava()